# VBA: How do you declare variables if the name is two words?

Tags: vba, excel

This is pretty much just a general question, but I guess this could be an example.

I've a worksheet named "all stocks". Since the name is two words, I'm not able to declared this as a worksheet, how do you get around this?

```
Dim all stocks as Worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "All Stocks"
```

Comment: I define it like what you did; but let me go a little bit further: `Set AllStocks = Worksheets("all stocks")`. If you are asking to define a variable in VBA with spaces in its name then I should say you cannot do that.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. What does *define something* mean? What is *something*, and how are you attempting to *define it* as a worksheet? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear what you're asking, and keep in mind while doing so that we have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do other than what the words you put in your post explain - we can't see your screen or read your mind in order to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, I was not that clear. What I meant to write was declare, not define. It was pretty much just a general question about VBA, since I've had this problem more than once. I edited the question, with an example to what I meant.

Comment: Variable names can only contain certain characters - a space is not one of them. You can call it whatever you want, so @Masoud has good advice

Comment: You don't. This is explicitly not allowed.

Comment: You can read more about VBA variables here http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson03.htm

Comment: The solution is to use a naming convention, formerly known as `PascalCase`: capitalize the first letter of each word; use it for modules and their members, public fields and globals, constants. Then use `camelCase` (first letter lowercase, then capitalize first letter of each word) for local variables, and parameters if you can. Note that VBA being case-insensitive makes `camelCase`-naming a bit harder to find good names for things. Whatever you do, avoid `Snake_Case` for public members.

Comment: Also, see [VBA language specification section 3.3.5: Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200272.aspx) for the formal definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable must have a name. The name is written on the right side of the Dim word. There are rules you should follow when naming your variables:

The name of a variable must begin with a letter or an underscore

After starting with a letter or an underscore, the name can be made of letters, underscores, and digits in any order

The name of a variable cannot have a period

The name of a variable can have up to 255 characters.

The name of a variable must be unique in the area where it is used

There are some words you should (must) not use to name your variables. Those words are reserved for the VBA internal use. Therefore, those words are called keywords. Some of them are:
And (Bitwise)   And (Condition)     As  Boolean     ByRef   Byte
ByVal   Call    Case    CBool   CByte   CDate
CDbl    CInt    CLng    Const   CSng    CStr
Date    Dim     Do  Double  Each    Else
ElseIf  End     EndIf   Error   False   For
Function    Get     GoTo    If  Integer     Let
Lib     Long    Loop    Me  Mid     Mod
New     Next    Not     Nothing     Option  Or (Bitwise)
Or (Condition)  Private     Public  ReDim   REM     Resume
Select  Set     Single  Static  Step    String
Sub     Then    To  True    Until   vbCrLf
vbTab   With    While   Xor

As mentioned already, to declare a variable, type Dim followed by a name.

Source: http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson03.htm

Comment: "area" would be more correct as "scope". Note that VBA allows mind-blowingly ambiguous naming regardless.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not able to declared this as a worksheet, how do you get around this?

Well, you don't need to *declare* worksheets, because they already exist, and can be accessed by Name, Index, or CodeName.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1")   'Name
Worksheets(1)          'Index
Sheet1                 'CodeName
```

You can assign any of these to a `Worksheet` class object variable and the results will be the same:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)
MsgBox ws.Name
Set ws = Sheet1
MsgBox ws.Name
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
MsgBox ws.Name
```

And you can change the pointer to another object just by reassignment:

```
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")  'Now ws represents Sheet2 instead of Sheet1
```

And so on.

Also, there is no reason why a (generic) variable container needs to correspond exactly with the string literal name of the object, you can declare a variable of type `Worksheet`:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "All Stocks"
```